# Error al cambiar la opción en Combobox Angular

Tags: angular

tengo el siguiente combobox generado dinámicamente en angular muestro código :

```html
<td *ngIf="item2.tipoInput == 'combo'">
  <select class="form-control" name="" [(ngModel)]="opcombo" (change)="cambiaCombo(item2.numIndividualf)" id="" style="width: 200px;">
    <option>Selecciona Una Opcción</option>
    <option>
      N/A
    </option>
    <option>
      PASS
    </option>
    <option>
      FAIL
    </option>

  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" id="" name="{{item2.tempPass}}" [checked]="Oprowopertion === item2.numIndividualf && PassFailop === 'PASS'" value="first_checkbox">

</td>
```

El problema es que cuando selecciono uno se cambian todos los valores dejo imagen de ejemplo : [image: seleccion pass]
ejemplo : [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se deberían mantener las opciones independientes en cada td por item , alguna sugerencia dentro del código que manejo ?.

Comment: Debe existir un `opcombo` individual para cada `td`.

Comment: Corregido , ahora el problema sede en los checks, al colocarse true o false en cualquiera se cambia el anterior cada check tiene un id diferente no se porque toma el valor de otro cada selección.

Comment: El id que muestras es `id=""` por lo que, es el mismo para todos, cada uno asegurate de identificarlos individualmente... Pon algo tipo `id="{{ item2.tipoInput }}"`

Comment: Cambie esas lineas por el id="{{item2.numIndividualf}}" name="{{item2.tempPass}}"  , value="{{item2.numIndividualf}}" ya los cambie, pero aún asi al seleccionar pass se cambia el check de arriba o abajo según sea el caso